# apache default virtual host configuration for www domain name

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Here is my apache default configuration for virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/mydir">
    AllowOverride FileInfo Limit Options Indexes
   </Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride none
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

This works well for http://mydomain.com but not for http://www.mydomain.com
How to serve my domain with www ?

This problem is only for default domains, my other domains work for both with this config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName otherdomain.com
ServerAlias www.otherdomain.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/otherdomain

ServerSignature Off
<Directory />
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/otherdomain>
    Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/otherdomain.com_access.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/otherdomain.com_error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect to happen, what happens instead, and what do the logs say?

Comment: If I access http://www.defaultdomain.com then browser shows "server not found" error. It works for http://defaultdomain.com

Comment: Maybe it is a stupid question, but...DNS record for www is properly configured?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell apache the server names of each virtualhost using the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` parameters.

Like:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com whatever.mydomain.com
    ...
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: Please check default config file code, it has no ServerName                                               <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www  ....                                         serverAlias works for otherdomain config, but there is no servername in default so how to put serverAlias there?

Comment: besides the serverconfig, you also have to make sure that your DNS is pointing to the right IPs

Comment: DNS is pointing to correct IP. It should be simple but seems I am missing something. All other domain urls are working with ServerName and ServerAlias but there is no ServerName in default config so I can not put any ServerAlias. Still thanks for your help.

Comment: If this is the default domain, then all requests that don't match any other virtualhost will go to that domain by default, so in this particular case there's no need to enter any ServerAlias.

Answer (score 0):

If the response you get is "Server not found", then I'd lay a bet that there **is** something wrong with your DNS settings. Unfortunately since you've chosen to hide the actual domainname it's impossible for anybody here to help you figure out what that might be. However, here's a simple way to verify whether it is DNS or the apache config that's the problem

First, do `nslookup www.yourdomain.com` on the same machine that you're browsing from. Do you get an IP in return? If so, is it the one you'd expect?

Second, Instead of using a browser to the server, use telnet to talk directly to it. Like this:

```
[jenny@jennys:~]$ telnet your.server.ip.here 80
Trying your.server.ip.here...
Connected to your.server.name (your.server.ip.here).
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yourdomainname.com
```

Make sure to press the Enter key twice after entering your domain name. Then post the output here.